# Running Swift Perfect and NGINX

Tags: swift, nginx, perfect

So I have a Swift server-side app running on my Ubuntu box, it's using the Perfect Framework and runs on port 8080.

I want NGINX to forward requests on port 80 to port 8080 (behind the scenes)

My config is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name burf.co;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
    } }
```

I have done similar things with VueJS, Node etc but for what am I missing here?
Is it a Perfect issue?
When I go to 127.0.0.1:8080 the page renders fine